# Dictionary not defined after module import with this dictionary Python 3.4

Tags: module, scope, python-3.4

I guess, I still don't fully understand scope rules in python (Was sure I do!), so please answer with some explanation.

I wrote module like this:

```
import pickle

question_dictionary = {}

#few not important definitions of functions
def functionA():
    blabla
def functionB():
    blabla
#and few classes
def Class1:
    blabla
#and here was my last class, maybe important for this problem:
def Class2:
    def __init__(self)
        blabla
        question_dictionary[blabla] = self
```

So, I import this file in interactive mode. Classes work good, also functions. But when i type in interactive mode question_dictionary I got information, that it's not defined. I don't understand why.

I tied to initialize another dictionary in interactive mode, and it work, the code "dictionary = {}" is valid.

I also tried to comment out the last lines:

```
question_dictionary[blabla] = self
```

But I still got problem, "NameError: name 'question_dictionary' is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dictionary is part of the globals of your *module*. You can reference it as such:

```
import yourmodule

yourmodule.question_dictionary
```

Globals are always per module, and your interactive interpreter namespace is really a module too (called `__main__`). You can create a new reference in that namespace by using `from ... import ...`:

```
from yourmodule import question_dictionary

# now question_dictionary is another reference to the same dictionary
```